# Open type shortcut (ctrl+shift+t) does not work in Flash Builder standalone/plugin

Tags: adobe, flash-builder

I've recently started developing flash and have been getting accustomed to the weirdness of flash builder.  Fortunately, I've had exposure to eclipse for java development, so I'm at least familiar with things like the project, preference structure and shortcuts.

One issue that I've run into for both the standalone and plugin client though is that the shortcut for open type (ctrl+shift+t on windows) doesn't seem to work.  However, the one for open resource (ctrl+shift+r on windows) works perfectly.  I've added my source folder to the source path, so that shouldn't be the problem.

The key binding for this is the default one:
Command: Open Type, Binding: Ctrl+Shift+T, When: Flash Builder Global Scope, Category:Navigation, User: (none)

Has anyone else run into this issue?  Any ideas for fixing this?  I rely heavily on open type.

Comment: ... and somehow, it is magically working after I restarted flash builder standalone.  It wasn't working for the longest time for the plugin version, so I switched to the standalone.  And then it wasn't working even after a few restarts, so I wrote this post. But now it does.  My question is why.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced the same error. Here's my solution:

`Preference` -> `General` -> `Keys`. Then type without quotes: `Open Type` in field where itg states "type filter here". Then select in "When:" In Action Script Mode. And then press "OK". 
Its work in MXML and ActionScript.

Answer (score 1):

Customize Perspective -> “Command Groups Availability” -> Unchecked the “Flash Navigation“
This worked for me. Also check after this that the Preferences - keys - are set to defaults.